Firebase CLI login issue - failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
When firebase login is run i get
"failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate"
or
"Failed to make request to https://auth.firebase.tools/attest"
> npm install -g firebase-tools
npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE


The issue was cause because Eset was blocking the certificate I guess. To solve this go to Advanced setup > Protections > SSL/TLS > Application scan rules > Edit.

found it on git
